# Efficiently finding duplicates in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, list, time-complexity

I have the function below which searches an array for duplicate entries and then returns a list of the duplicates.  I'd like to speed this piece of my code up, can anyone suggest a more efficient way?

Code:

```
def findDupe(array):
    dupelist = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in range(len(array)):
            comp1 = array[i]
            comp2 = array[j]
            if comp1 == comp2 and i!=j:
                if comp2 not in dupelist:
                    dupelist.append(comp2)
    return dupelist
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea here is to do a single sweep in linear time. You can use a counter to do this. The idea is to count each element and then return all those which were counted multiple times.

```
from collections import Counter

def get_duplicates(array):
    c = Counter(array)
    return [k for k in c if c[k] > 1]
```

---

The approach above is linear in complexity, but makes two passes over the input - once, to count (this is abstracted away by the `Counter` constructor) and the other is to return non-unique values in the list comp. You can optimise this a bit using a `yield` statement, and return duplicates as you find them.

```
def get_duplicates(array):
    c = Counter()
    seen = set()
    for i in array: 
        c[i] += 1
        if c[i] > 1 and i not in seen:
            seen.add(i)
            yield i
```

This results in a compulsory `if` check and extra space in the form of a `set`, but you reduce two passes to one.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thank you for getting back to me so quickly!  So if I understand correctly the run time for your final suggestion would be a linear function of the input array.  Is that correct?  How does that differ from the run time of the original function I provided?

Comment: @user3476463 You have a loop within a loop. This means that your function is quadratic, which is much much slower than linear.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Hi, I tried printing the results of your suggestion with testArray = ['a','b','c','d','e','d'] using print get_duplicates(testArray) and I'm getting the following message <generator object get_duplicates at 0x107609eb0> , if I want to print the results what do I need to do?  I'm not very familiar with generators.

Comment: @user3476463 Yes, `yield` returns a generator. Convert to a list using: `x = list(get_duplicates(...))`

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thank you, much quicker than previous version!

Comment: @user3476463 yes! That's the power of time complexity analysis.

Comment: @COLDSPEED  I added the results of using %timeit to the original post.  It looks like if I add list() I'm not getting a gain in run time.  Am I not using %timeit correctly?  Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @user3476463 Well, the thing with time complexity, is you usually don't see a difference unless your input size increases. For example, if I replace your example with a list of size 1000, your method takes 200ms, while mine takes 1ms. For data of size 1 million, your function will take hours to complete, while mine takes one and a half seconds :)

Comment: `[k for k in c if c[k] > 1]` or even `[k for k, v in c.items() if 1 < v]`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of elements in your lists?

1. Storing elements in a Set, as explained above, gives you average complexity Θ(n) but requires the elements to be hashable (a Set in Python is implemented with hash table, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)
2. If you have a comparison function, you can sort the list in worst case Θ(nlog(n)) then compare each element of the list to the next.
3. If you have a comparison function, you can also implement a set with a (balanced) BST and do the same as 1 to achieve complexity Θ(nlog(n)) in average (in worst case).

Answer (score 0):

While `numpy` does not have the `duplicated` method (yet), `pandas` does:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series(input_list)

duplicated_values = df[df.duplicated()].to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative with no imports required:

```
dups = set()
distinct_ids = set()
for an_id in ids:
    if an_id not in distinct_ids:
        distinct_ids.add(an_id)
    else:
        dups.add(an_id)
```